# Using GWT UiBinder, Eclipse marks every UiField as an error

Tags: eclipse, uibinder

This is an annoyance, not a serious problem, but it bothers me that I can't figure it out. I have a GWT project and Eclipse is marking every @UiField tag with the error "Field X has not corresponding field in the template file."

When this is actually true I will get a compile error and can fix it. Most of the time it compiles and runs fine, even though my files are full of red squiggly underlines.

I assume I'm missing some basic Eclipse skill since I can't find anybody else with this problem. I've tried doing a refresh on the project.

Comment: I feel your pain.  One minute, it finds everything correctly, the next, bam! Red everywhere!  I'll let you know if I find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It is not a code issue as suggested by @ruggi as the project compiles and runs correctly.

I solved the problem by updating the GWT install. I found that there was an update available via Help -> Check for Updates. After install and reboot the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

The error implies that field X can not be found in the template file.

When i have this, this either is due to

- I did not create the template file

e.g a template file MyViewer.ui.xml pairing with a MyViewer.java

- I forgot to make a template file
- or I made a typo in a template file

e.g. with

```
@UiField
TextBox x;
```

in the java file there should be somewhere something like

```
<g:TextBox ui:field='x'" />
```

in the template file. I.e. there should be a `ui:field` matching the field name X in your java file.